# Arguments Not specified for parameter in private sub

Tags: vb.net

It is throwing the error argument not specified for the parameter(ReceiptTotal) of private sub InsertTempFile:
Kindly help me

```
Private Sub Search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim StrConn As String = My.Settings.ANOCS
    Dim CN = New SqlConnection(StrConn)
    Dim FromDate As Date = FromDateDateTimePicker.Value
    Dim ToDate As Date = ToDateDateTimePicker.Value


    InsertTempFile()

    Modws.DisplayDataGrid(dgvClosingBalance, "Select Customer, Sum(RptTempTable.INVOICETOTAL) As [Invoice Total], Sum(RptTempTable.CNTOTAL) As [CN Total], Sum(RptTempTable.DEBITTOTAL) As [DN Total], Sum(RptTempTable.RECEIPTTOTAL) As [Receipt Total] From RptTempTable group by Customer")

End Sub
```

The InsertTempFile Code:

```
Private Sub InsertTempFile(ByVal CUSTOMER As String, ByVal INVOICETOTAL As String, ByVal DEBITTOTAL As String, ByVal RECEIPTTOTAL As String, ByVal CNTOTAL As String)

    Dim FromDate As Date = FromDateDateTimePicker.Value
    Dim ToDate As Date = ToDateDateTimePicker.Value

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(RECEIPTTOTAL) select Debtor,Sum(Matching.Amt) from Matching left join receipt on receipt.pkey = matching.crpk left join invoice on invoice.Pkey = matching.drpk" + _
                    " where invoice.transdate between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and receipt.transdate between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and drtype = 12 and crtype = 7 group by matching.debtor")

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(CNTOTAL) Select Debtor,Sum(AMT) from Matching left join CREDITNOTE on CREDITNOTE.Pkey = Matching.CRPK left join Invoice on Invoice.Pkey = Matching.DRPK" + _
                    " where Invoice.TRANSDATE  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and CREDITNOTE.CNDATE between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and drtype = 12 and crtype = 8 group by Matching.Debtor")

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(DEBITTOTAL) Select Debtor,Sum(AMT) from Matching left join DEBITNOTE on DEBITNOTE.Pkey = Matching.CRPK left join Invoice on Invoice.Pkey = Matching.DRPK" + _
                    " where Invoice.TRANSDATE  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and DEBITNOTE.DNDATE between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "'  and drtype = 12 and crtype = 6 group by Matching.Debtor")

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(INVOICETOTAL) Select Debtor,Sum(AMT) from Matching left join INVOICE on INVOICE.Pkey = Matching.CRPK" + _
                    " where Invoice.TRANSDATE  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and drtype = 12 and crtype = 12 group by Matching.Debtor")

End Sub
```

Comment: the error is in the InsertTempFile()

Comment: Is expecting the parameters:
`(CUSTOMER ByVal As String, ByVal InvoiceTotal As String, ByVal DEBITTOTAL As String, ByVal RECEIPTTOTAL As String, ByVal CNTOTAL As String)` in procedure `InsertTempFile()`. If you're not using those parameters you can delete them from the procedure definition.

Comment: How to do that? How to amend the code?

Comment: Change `Private Sub InsertTempFile(ByVal CUSTOMER As String, ByVal INVOICETOTAL As String, ByVal DEBITTOTAL As String, ByVal RECEIPTTOTAL As String, ByVal CNTOTAL As String)` to `Private Sub InsertTempFile()` since you are not using them anyway.

Comment: thank you so much it wrks now but when i run the query it show the conversion of char datatype to datetime data type value was out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution where you just need to remove the arguments from the method. Your `Search_Click` method will remain same.

```
    Private Sub InsertTempFile()

    Dim FromDate As Date = FromDateDateTimePicker.Value
    Dim ToDate As Date = ToDateDateTimePicker.Value

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(RECEIPTTOTAL) select Debtor,Sum(Matching.Amt) from Matching left join receipt on receipt.pkey = matching.crpk left join invoice on invoice.Pkey = matching.drpk" + _
                    " where invoice.transdate between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and receipt.transdate between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and drtype = 12 and crtype = 7 group by matching.debtor")

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(CNTOTAL) Select Debtor,Sum(AMT) from Matching left join CREDITNOTE on CREDITNOTE.Pkey = Matching.CRPK left join Invoice on Invoice.Pkey = Matching.DRPK" + _
                    " where Invoice.TRANSDATE  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and CREDITNOTE.CNDATE between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and drtype = 12 and crtype = 8 group by Matching.Debtor")

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(DEBITTOTAL) Select Debtor,Sum(AMT) from Matching left join DEBITNOTE on DEBITNOTE.Pkey = Matching.CRPK left join Invoice on Invoice.Pkey = Matching.DRPK" + _
                    " where Invoice.TRANSDATE  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and DEBITNOTE.DNDATE between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "'  and drtype = 12 and crtype = 6 group by Matching.Debtor")

    Modws.UpdateItem("Insert into RptTempTable(INVOICETOTAL) Select Debtor,Sum(AMT) from Matching left join INVOICE on INVOICE.Pkey = Matching.CRPK" + _
                    " where Invoice.TRANSDATE  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "' and drtype = 12 and crtype = 12 group by Matching.Debtor")

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much it wrks now but when i run the query it show the conversion of char datatype to datetime data type value was out of range

Answer (score 0):

The `InsertTempFile` procedure should be as follows:

```
    Private Sub InsertTempFile()
    ...

    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much it wrks now but when i run the query it show the conversion of char datatype to datetime data type value was out of range